# Why do I turn into a fireball when I exit power armor?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I am working with mods, so that may be the issue, but it's annoying because I entered a suit of power armor and when I exited my character was in a fireball. If I enter the power armor I return to normal, but when I leave I'm a fireball. The fire doesn't go away and is surprisingly annoying. Is there any way to remove it? This is on PS4, by the way.

FINAL EDIT: Problem solved, had a fire shield ability activated and disabled it.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get rid of it? Like fast travel, entering or exiting a building, switching clothing/armor, changing your appearance in Diamond City, getting a haircut, etc?

Comment: I've tried a few of those, exiting the game and rejoining and going to new places, but I'll try some of your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `player.dispelallspells` ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sgc29/getting_rid_of_molerat_disease/): Getting rid of Molerat Disease?)

Or `player.resurrect` ([Nexus](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/541809-need-to-remove-active-effects-via-console/page-2), Skyrim: Need to Remove Active Effects via console.)

You may have to do one or the other, save, and then restart.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this is PS4

Comment: Well then, I'm sorry too. Go jump in a river? ;)

Comment: Done that. Apparently power armor fireballs are water resistant ¯\_(ツ)_/¯